Apache POI docx to pdf Exception CTTblGrid.getGridColList because grid is null
We have a predefined document docx file. We are using Apache POI java program to convert docx to PDF.
Java program is used only to convert docx to PDF - nothing else.

Java program receives the file as a stream of bytes (base64 from Azure cloud running as a function app)
Java program converts the file to a PDF stream of bytes

Simplified Java code:
InputStream instrm = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
ByteArrayOutputStream outstrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(instrm);
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(instrm, outstrm, options);

//outstrm is the one that is n output from the java component

This worked fine, including the document having a small image (company logo) and a predefined table.
We needed to add another table programmatically to the document. Another group did this new table adding using the C# DocumentFormat.OpenXml package.
Simplified C# code (again running as Azure Function App):
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

var outputStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(prependBase64String));
Table table  = new Table();
var tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("SimpleText"))));
tr.Append(tc);
table.Append(tr);

When C# program runs, it creates document absolutly fine. When I open docx file using MS Word UI I can see table with one cell created.
Problem:
However, now feeding this new docx file with dynamically created new table into my Java program throws an Exception: "CTTblGrid.getGridColList grid is null" full exception reads: fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblGrid.getGridColList()" because "grid" is null
To note here - if I open this Word document, and issue a "Save As" without changing anything, and feed this file document into my Java component, Java does work converting this document including the dynamic table into PDF format.
Something Word is doing during the Save operation to "fix" something within that programatically generated table.

To understand what is really done by Word, have you tried unzipping both the docx (before and after saving) and comparing the word\document.xml files? Using this information, you may find if there is something that has to be changed on the C# routine or as a pre-processing before the java pdf conversion.

It seems like using Table is enough for Microsoft Word to open a document, but not enough if you want to use Apache POI to save a document containing the table as a PDF. You have to add the TableGrid Openxml object to the Table object.
